Chinese chars can not be displayed properly with ncursesw on MinGW(ucrt64) env
Recently I want to build a cross-platform tui program with C, using libncursesw. I tried to test multiple solutions as listed: (phenomenon talked below is the displaying result of string containing Chinese characters)

msys ncurses with char string => proper
ucrt64 version with char string => misaligned
ucrt64 version with wchar_t string => no display in cmd, misaligned in msys
official build with char string => iconved string like M-f~L~IM-e...
official build with wchar_t string => no display

Althogh it seems that msys is what I want, it can not run in cmd, showing Error opening terminal: xterm-256color. So ucrt64 version (that is, linking the program with /ucrt64/bin/libncursesw6.dll) might be the possible solution. The final challenge to overcome is the misalignment as the screenshot shows.


Hint: the misalignment in the screenshot is 6-byte-long, the length of the Chinese string. The string include 6 characters, and displayed in 12 bytes, but ncursesw treats it as 6-byte-long, which causes this problem

What's more, the behavior under real cmd.exe is even more weird. Characters are overlapped like this:

Here is the code to replicate:
#include <ncurses/ncurses.h>
#include <locale.h>

void print_centered(WINDOW *win, int start_row, int width, const char *str) {
    int col_width = 0;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ) {
        col_width += (str[i] & 0x80) ? (i += 3, 2) : (i++, 1);
    }

    int x = (width - col_width) / 2;
    mvwaddstr(win, start_row, x, str);
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "zh_CN.UTF-8");

    initscr();
    noecho();
    cbreak();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    int height, width, start_y, start_x;
    height = 10;
    width = 40;
    start_y = (LINES - height) / 2;
    start_x = (COLS - width) / 2;

    WINDOW *win = newwin(height, width, start_y, start_x);
    box(win, 0, 0);

    print_centered(win, 2, width, "hello ncurses");
    print_centered(win, height - 3, width, "按回车键退出");

    wrefresh(win);

    int ch;
    while ((ch = wgetch(win)) != '\n') {}

    delwin(win);
    endwin();

    return 0;
}


Just declare the cmd window obsolete. It obviously doesn't support double-width characters out of the box. Perhaps you need to output a space after each, or something.

@n.m.couldbeanAI I know what you mean, but it's so weird that if you echo some Chinese words or printf them, they will not get overlapped. So cmd should have out-of-box double-width char support. I just tried PDcurses and found that the box now aligned up, but characters still got overlapped.

I'm now debugging the libncursesw, if anyone could tell me how to load the source will help much! (I downloaded the source code and make it with debuginfo)
